# iOS NSNotification for speaker phone event or determine if speaker phone in use

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

A UITextView I have in my view gets bumped down a bit when the device has the speaker phone on (a green bar shows at the top).  Is there an event listen for, or, how else could I prevent the UI from being altered when the green speaker phone bar is showing?

My app is targeting >= iOS 7.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prevent the status bar change, but you can receive a notification that the bar is or has changed.

The [`application:didChangeStatusBarFrame:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidChangeStatusBarFrame%3a) method in your app delegate will be called when they status bar changes.  There is also `application:willhangeStatusBarFrame:` that gets called before the change.

Additionally, the [`UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification) will be posted when the status bar changes  too - so your view controllers can subscribe to that in order to handle the change directly.

However, depending on your UI, properly configured constraints and auto layout can deal with this in many cases.

In the simulator you can test by using the "Toggle In-Call Status Bar" command from the Hardware menu.